# Cyrillic content of attached to email file has wrong encoding when sending it with email in Python

Tags: python, json, email, encoding

I have a json file with this content, it has cyrillic letters.

```
{
  "Полотенцесушитель EF 600L (белый)": {
    "sku": "Полотенцесушитель EF 600L (белый)",
    "price": "2 690 грн",
    "link": "https://example.org/some_link_bla_bla"
  },
```

I attach this file to email and send it with this code:

```
def send_email(subject: str, json_file_path):
    """Send email."""
    m = MIMEMultipart()
    m.add_header("from", sender)
    m.add_header("to", receiver)
    m.add_header("subject", subject)

    if json_file_path:
        with open(json_file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            attachment = MIMEApplication(file.read(), _subtype="json")
            attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename='file.json')
            m.attach(attachment)

    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    try:
        with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(
            smtp_server, smtp_port, context=context, timeout=20
        ) as server:
            server.login(smtp_username, smtp_password)
            server.sendmail(sender, receiver, m.as_string())
        ic("Email sent")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(e)
        ic(e)
```

It works, but all cyrillic letters in the attached file become like:

```
{
  "\u041f\u043e\u043b\u043e\u0442\u0435\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0441\u0443\u0448\u0438\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044c EF 600L (\u0431\u0435\u043b\u044b\u0439)": {
    "sku": "\u041f\u043e\u043b\u043e\u0442\u0435\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0441\u0443\u0448\u0438\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044c EF 600L (\u0431\u0435\u043b\u044b\u0439)",
    "price": "2 690 \u0433\u0440\u043d",
    "link": "https://example.org/some_link_bla_bla"
  },
```

How to fix that issue?

Comment: to avoid decoding/encoding the file, read the file in binary mode: `open(json_file_path, 'rb')`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, share all `import`s as well as how do you call your function…

Comment: The attached file appears to be a valid JSON file using escaped characters for Cyrillic. Have you tried setting the email charset to UTF-8?

Comment: I'd be inclined to use the json package to read the json file to a string then use `MIMEText(json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii = False))` instead of using `MIMEApplication`